Google Play Console restringió mi cuenta y elimino mis apps
Hola devs tengo un problema mi cuenta en Google Play está restringida y mis apps se eliminaron. Desde hace 6 años tengo la cuenta y nunca tuve problemas, hace unas semanas me pidieron verificar mi identidad para lo cual subí mi documento y me restringieron mi cuenta y eliminaron mis apps sin darme ningún tipo de explicación ni posibilidad de volver a subir documentación!. Supuse que el problema fue que di de baja una tarjeta de crédito a mi nombre, pero subi dos tarjetas nuevas a mi nombre y no pasó nada!. En un intento casi desesperado pague 25 dolares por otra cuenta, esta vez me dieron mas intentos de subir documentación, me pidieron volver a subir mi documento pero me respondian que no se podia verificar mi identidad y al tercer intento tambien quedó restringida. Ni siquiera me devuelven el dinero! Alguien que me pueda ayudar? Muchas Gracias!

Y no seria mejor hablarlo con el soporte de ellos? que tipo de respuesta esperas aca?

Desde que restringieron mi cuenta he abierto cerca de 50 reclamos y se cierran sin darme ningún tipo de explicación. Lo que espero es alguien que haya tenido la misma experiencia con problemas de verificación de identidad, si no la tenes y no podes ayudar, podes evitar responder.

Podes evitar también comunicarte de esa forma con alguien que trata de ayudarte. No descargues tu frustracion en un sitio que no tiene nada que ver.  Si esa es la clase de ayuda que esperas, genial, pero sin saber que pasos hiciste antes, dificil que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Los pasos ya los expliqué, vos preguntas sacando de contexto que tipo de respuesta espero acá, y la respuesta es obvia, es una pregunta a un problema, espero una respuesta de alguien que puede tener la solución. Si alguien no tiene la respuesta, tiene que evitar responder, es evidente que sos vos el que descarga frustración acá.

Es que yo no respondi.. te invito a que hagas el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio.. te pregunto que tipo de respuestas esperas, porque contestarte comunicate con soporte al usuario seria una respuesta valida a tu pregunta.

Te pongo en contexto. Desde Julio 2023 Google anunció que los desarrolladores debían validar su identidad. Llego mi fecha en Junio y al subir mi documento me bloquearon la cuenta, así, sin más. Hay muchas razones posibles que tienen que ver con la calidad de la imagen, una tarjeta a nombre de otra persona o incoherencias en el nombre de la cuenta y la tarjeta. No pareciera ser mi caso, desconozco la razón porque no dan explicaciones, solo una posibilidad de apelar y luego cierran tu cuenta. Se de casos que lograron reactivarla, por eso estoy acá. No hay soporte, ni herramientas de seguimiento.
